# Do two or more subcircuits connected together change behavior?

Tags: bjt, 741-opamp, subcircuit

This circuit for example:

[image]

This is an op-amp circuit. It contains several subcircuits.

I want to know how I can analyze this circuit. I found that I need to break the circuit into subcircuits, but I still don't understand. Do subcircuits change behavior when they are connected together?

Does each subcircuit still work like when they are unconnected to another subcircuit? And if it still works like when they are unconnected, how can I show that this is true in my analysis?

And if I want to learn more about this, what articles do I need to read?

Comment: Reading circuits is like reading hieroglyphics; you can take one object (say a scarab beetle) and fully remember what that is but, if you didn't know that a scarab beetle was associated with two other hieroglyphs namely the falcon and some 3 lines representing water you wouldn't see his proper name i.e. Tut-anhk-amun. Hence you just need to keep slogging away. Don't hang me if I got the glyphs wrong.

Comment: The 741 op-amp circuit came from here: https://how2electronics.com/op-amp-ic-lm741-basics-characteristics-pins-applications/

Comment: @Andy aka       Thank you . I have a problem to understand this point this sounds stupid : when connected subcircuit (for example amplifier ) to other subcircuit before I think that amplifier circuit will change behavior such as change from amplifier to other function because there are other circuit connected therefore I think it also change behavior but now It's not something like that , each subcircuit are still work the same as when they connect alone right?

Comment: Sub-circuits don't usually work the same way when they connect to other sub-circuits. For instance, an amplifier can be caused to oscillate when connected to a sub-circuit or a different sub-circuit.

Comment: Thank you . quote "Sub-circuits don't usually work the same way when they connect to other sub-circuits" does that mean amplifier when connected to other circuit it will not amplify ?  But what about other circuit for example circuit above there are differential amplifier , current mirror, they are connected together each circuit still work their own function.

Comment: Or does that mean it can amplify but we need to design to make it amplify not be caused oscillate ?

Comment: An amplifier when connected to another circuit may be just fine, amplify less, amplify more, become unstable, burn, get noisy, turn into an oscillator or just stop working as expected. This is why we define the interface parameters between sub-circuits and why data sheets for components (sub-circuits in their own rights) have such a lot of detail about interfacing. @heroz

Comment: Thank you. Circuit above they marked the section , each section still work their own function in ideal right? for example blue section they still differential amplify although they connected to other sub-circuit . @Andyaka

Comment: No they won't; it's more complicated than this (just like trying to figure out hieroglyphs). One day the curtain will lift (that's how it happened with me).

Comment: Thank you . Sorry for ask you many question , but when they design circuit they connected several sub-circuit together How do they know it will not change behavior ? or as you said they use interface parameter between sub-circuit to design. @Andyaka

Comment: Is it about input and output impedance matching?

Comment: No, it's more complex that that; it's loading effects across the spectrum of signals to be considered.

Answer (score 2):

All the subcircuits depend on each other. They are designed and built that way. Their inputs and outputs are compatible and biased to correct operating point by the red biasing circuits.

For example the cyan output circuit does not work alone, it needs the green Vbe multiplier to work. But you can replace it with ideal voltage source if you want to simulate cyan circuit only.

If you want to separately simulate a subsection, it is possibly by biasing the circuit and signals to similar operating points with ideal current and voltage sources. But for that you need to already know a lot about how the circuit operates.

Since you pasted a picture of op-amp internals from Wikipedia here without attribution, you can also read the Wikipedia article for details how that circuit works.

Answer (score 1):

*This isn't supposed to be an answer but became too long for a comment.*

> I want to know how I can analyze this circuit.

Please don't get offended but this seems a bit too much for a beginner level. Today, even in the electrical and electronics engineering departments of universities the internals of an op-amp is kept out-of-scope.

> I found that I need to break the circuit into subcircuits, but I still don't understand.

Breaking into sub-circuits and analysing each section is a good way. But

- Sectioning requires familiarity, of course. You can't make sectioning randomly. I assume you are the one who marked the sections with colourful dash-dot lines. So you should be familiar with each section.
- Sections may be meaningful with adjacent sections i.e. the sub-circuits interact with each other. So, for example, the long-tailed pair may not be fully analysed/understood without analysing the current source. Likewise, the Vbe multiplier can't work without a current source.

Now I can see a long-tailed pair, current sources/limiters, current mirrors, Vbe multiplier, and a class AB amplifier. If you want to analyse the entire circuit, you should know how to analyse these transistor circuits/amplifiers first. Then, looking at the circuit, you can analyse the interaction between each. This will hopefully make the total analyse easier.

Comment: Most of my circuits 2 (if I remember right) class in university consisted of building up, over the course of an entire semester, from a single BJT to an op amp. It's a pretty complicated thing to learn if you don't know the basics.

Comment: @Hearth I don't know what year was it but you must be lucky then. Today things are different. In early 2000s, my Circuit-1 was full of amplifiers (types, classes, feedback etc), and Circuits-2 covered transistor circuit applications in general e.g. regulators, logic circuts, oscillators, etc. and an introduction to PA design (especially class AB) to show how different types can be combined together. I remember that the professor said "today op amps are no different than this PA, only the driving capability is lower". There were no time to cover an op amp design :) It's almost the same today.

Comment: That would have been... Probably 2013 or 2014?